# Autoplay for movie DVDs in Windows 10 is not displaying programs

Tags: windows-10, dvd, autoplay

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 110 with Windows 10 Home. Whenever I load a **movie DVD**, the **autoplay dialog box** comes up showing two options: "Find a new DVD app" (Microsoft Store) or "Take no action".

I have installed on my computer **VLC** and **Windows Media player** and tried many of the apps from the Microsoft Store, but **none of them show up in dialog box** when I insert a DVD. I am able to play the movie manually from VLC but I can't get it done automatically. Also, the autoplay works properly with other sources such us music CDs and USBs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\PlayDVDMovieOnArrival]
"FindAppPlayDVDMovieOnArrival"=""
"VLCPlayDVDMovieOnArrival"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\PlayDVDAudioOnArrival]
"VLCPlayDVDAudioOnArrival"=""
```

1. Open Notepad, copy the above contents and paste it.
2. Save the file with `.REG` extension, say `autoplaydvd.reg`.
3. Double-click the REG file to apply the settings to the registry.

VLC Player entry should now show up in DVD autoplay dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it didn't work... VLC still does't show up in the dialog box.